# 240v four-wire motor to three-prong welder plug?

Tags: electrical

Yes I am trying to wire a hydraulic hose making machine it has 4 wires red, black, white and green to work on my 3 prong welder plug and I can't figure out how to wire the plug on the motor

Comment: You don't.  The machine requires a neutral(white) wire.  You have two hots(red and black) and a ground(green).  Imagine some controls require 120v provided by the one white and one hot.

Comment: Can you post more information about how the machine is wired?

Comment: The red and black are the phases, white in neutral, and the most important is green, it is the ground that keeps you from getting zaped or killed if the unit faults. There are ways to do it but since none of them are safe however I will not mention them. Best to keep you safe.

Answer (score 2):

### Not gonna work

Motors don't need neutral.

However, many motors on industrial equipment are **3-phase**.   When they are, they often use the white wire as one of the phases (because those are the standard colors in common cables).

That is almost assuredly what you have, and that's why it's not working.

Your best bet is to change the motor out to a single phase motor.